# Delphi Event Listener only executing the first time

Tags: delphi, events, listener

Overview:
   I have an application were we want to listen/test events, the ideal is
   to pass an event name to a stored procedure and be able to report
   back it event was successful and/or unsuccessful.

Issue:
   Event is only getting executed the first time, subsequent event don’t
   get executed. (see NotifyEventAlert)

Stored Procedure:

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE TESTEVENT(EVENTNAME VARCHAR(65))
   AS
   BEGIN
     POST_EVENT(:EVENTNAME);
   END;
```

NotifyEventAlert:

```
   //Note event is only getting excuted the first time
   procedure TObjApplicationEvents.NotifyEventAlert(Sender: TObject;
   EventName: string; EventCount: Integer; var CancelAlerts: Boolean);
   begin
       if Assigned(Self.OnPostedEvent) then
          Self.OnPostedEvent(Self, Eventname);
   end;
```

EventPosting :

```
    procedure TFrmEventProcessingTestLkp.btnTestEventClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      c : TCursor;
     ae : TObjApplicationEvents;
     cq : TCustomQuery;
    begin 
        inherited;
        c := Screen.Cursor;
        Screen.Cursor := crHourglass;
        ae := nil;
        cq := nil;
       try
         try
           ae := TObjApplicationEvents.Create;
           ae.OnPostedEvent := Self.OnPostedEvent;

           cq := TCustomQuery.Create(nil);
           cq.StartTransaction;
           cq.SetOperationType(cqotStoredProcedure);
           cq.SetStoredProcName('TESTEVENT');
           cq.Params.CreateParam(ftString, 'EVENTNAME', ptInput);
           cq.ParamByName('EVENTNAME').Value := GetRecordColumnValue(cxColEvent.Index);
           cq.ExecSQL;
           cq.CommitTransaction;
           Sleep(1000);
         except on e: Exception do
         begin
           cq.RollBackTransaction;
           raise Exception.Create(e.message);
         end;
      end;
   finally
      FreeAndNil(ae);
      FreeAndNil(cq);
      Screen.Cursor:= c;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Is this with Firebird SQL? And is TObjApplicationEvents your own code? Can you post the implementation for TObjApplicationEvents class otherwise I doubt anyone can help.

Comment: There's too much missing information here. What is the implementation of `TObjApplicationEvents`? What is the implementation of `TCustomQuery`? Both of those seem to be critical to the question, but you provide no information about either of them. I don't see how this question can be answered without those details.

Comment: All IB/FB components set like FIB+ or Unified Interbase or even Interbase Express already have event component. Why would one make a custom ad hoc one ?

And i would suspect that server would not spam network with all and every event instance. I think they are more like Signals, that had to be reset after handling. AFAIR (but aint sure) IB/FB anyway collapses all the events of same time into single instance to be send on transaction COMMIT. It would be natural to also signal from app to server when the handling would be complete. And most natural way of signalling would be re-subscribing.

Comment: Above is purely speculating. I think proper way would be to take the already existing library and re-use event monitor component and all the experience tis designers had.